# Perfect matching in 3-regular graph.

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that each vertex 2-connected, 3-regular graph has a perfect
>   matching.

Please give some advice. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I consider using Hall theorem, but I don't know how to apply.

Comment: Have you learned about [Tutte's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem)?

Comment: Hall's Theorem applies only to bipartite graphs.

Comment: and without using Tutte's Theorem?

Comment: See corollary 2.2.2 on page 43 in Diestel's "Graph Theory" 4th edition, ISBN-10: 3642142788.